# Is there a way to make ReportViewer to get paginated data?

Tags: .net, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

We're testing the native Visual Studio reporting technologies for ASP.NET (RDLC file + ReportViewer) to see if it meets our needs.

One flaw we have detected that makes it unfeasable to use is that, for some reason, when connected to our IDataSource, `the ReportViewer` does not ask for paginated data. It gets the `DataSourceView` and calls its `ExecuteSelectMethod` passing an `DataSourceSelectArguments` that does not ask for paginated data. The `CanPage` property of the `DataSourceView` returns true. It doesn't even ask for count.

On the other hand, the pagination on top of the control shows an uncertain number of pages, what makes us believe that there might be a way to work with paginated data.

*Is there a way to make it to work with paginated data? Is it a good reporting tool? If not, what are the options that meet this need?*

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a participant in [this discussion](http://forums.asp.net/t/1210489.aspx) there isn't any direct way to accomplish your objective:

ReportViewer does not have an option to load the data for the specific page the user is viewing. Data for the entire report must be provided upfront. You could design your RDL report which only contains one page. Then hide the default toolbar of ReportViewer and create your own paging controls. When the user navigates to the next page, re-execute the report with data for the next page

Disclaimer: I have not tried this myself.